# Create button inside service

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-service, android-service-binding

I want to ask for a solution from you guys, how do I create a button in the service then I can return the string value through the callback interface

Comment: Need more context. What does service do? And why Button from there?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.